# How to check if a game object is inside another gameobject

Tags: unity, gameobject

My idea is that there is a plane which is more of a border at top of the screen and if a game object has no more space to fall and it collides with something while it is in that border, the game ends. How can I check if a gameobject is inside that plane?

Example:
[image]

Comment: Could you please explain it little bit more?

Comment: So you only want to react on collision events when the object is within a given zone and react them otherwise? By the way, do you know what `Collider`s are in Unity?

Comment: I edited my post with a sketch example

Comment: Looks like you want a Collider volume that is marked as a [trigger](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers)

Comment: @Draco18s Can you show how this is done?

Comment: Look at the video tutorial supplied by Unity on the page that I linked?  A trigger volume is literally a single checkbox on the Collider component in the properties inspector panel.  Stuff ending up inside it is detected with a script with the `OnTriggerEnter()` [message method](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) attached to the same game object as the Collider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Danoweb's answer, here is how I did it:

```
public class CubeInteraction : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool endGameBorderCollided;
    private bool cubeCollided;

    private void Update() {
    //Check if there is any space left for cubes to fall. If not - end the game
    CheckForCubeOverflow();

    // Controls touch inputs by the user
    RegisterTouchInputs();
    }

    // Check if a cube enters the end game border and if it collides with another cube at that time
    private void CheckForCubeOverflow() {
       if (endGameBorderCollided && cubeCollided)
           gameOverController.EndGame();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider2D) {
       if (collider2D.name == "End Game Border")
           endGameBorderCollided = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider2D) {
       if (collider2D.name == "End Game Border")
           endGameBorderCollided = false;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision2D) {
       if (collision2D.collider.name.Contains("Cube"))
           cubeCollided = true;
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision2D) {
       if (collision2D.collider.name.Contains("Cube"))
           cubeCollided = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use case for Colliders in Unity.  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html

You would actually want to achieve your objective using 2 colliders.  The first being your Border Collider, the second being the "Play Space" collider.

You would then want a script for your GameObjects (squares/rectangles) which checks their collisions, and using a few variables determine which state you are describing.

An example (psuedo code) would be something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class falling_game_block : MonoBehaviour {

bool border_collide = false;
bool playspace_collide = false;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision_info) 
{
    if(collision_info.collider.name == "border_collider_name")
    {
        border_collide = true;
    }//END IF COLLISION.COLLIDER == "BORDER_COLLIDER_HERE"

    if(collision_info.collider.name == "playspace_collider_name")
    {
        playspace_collide = true;
    }//END IF COLLISION.COLLIDER == "PLAYSPACE_COLLIDER_HERE"

    print(gameObject.name + " in contact with " + collisionInfo.collider.name);
}//END FUNCTION ONCOLLISIONENTER

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collisionInfo) {
    print(gameObject.name + " No longer in contact with " + collisionInfo.collider.name);
}

void Update() 
{
    if(border_collide == true && playspace_collide == true)
    {
        //DO stuff, explode, warn, cry, etc...
    }//END IF BORDER_COLLIDE == TRUE AND PLAYSPACE_COLLIDE == TRUE
}
}//END CLASS FALLING_GAME_BLOCK
```

You'll want to look at the "console" to see the print messages.  Comment them out when you understand what is going on.

*** Note this is just psuedo code, and is not fully tested... you may have to perform slight tweaks to address errors, and a few more tweaks to get it to handle your exact need, but this should provide a good starting point!!!

Answer (score 0):

Physics2D.OverlapArea would be perfect for this use...

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. Why would it be perfect for this use? How should it be used? One-line answers tend to be deleted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/57676)

Comment: this built-in function seems like created for such cases : it checks if two colliders overlap (thats why it seemed obvious to me and needed no more explanations) place a rectangle collider in the 'game over zone' and do a check for other colliders presence on each turn. if it brings a result -> game over.