# How do I detect if two 3D box shapes are overlapping each other?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, 3d

I'm creating a Unity game, and for my building system inside the game, I need to detect if 2 3d box shapes are overlapping each other. What I'm doing this for is, lets say I'm building a wall, I need to detect if its overlapping another wall, or another specified shape. There will be a UI that turns red or green depending on whether its overlapping another shape. I researched a little, and I came across SphereOverlap, but it is not accurate enough for my needs.

I'm talking about a 3D context, not 2D.

Code examples(in c# preferred) would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a game object is inside another gameobject](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113936/how-to-check-if-a-game-object-is-inside-another-gameobject)

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree that this duplicates the linked question, because that one is about the 2D case. Although the method is similar in 3D, I think it's distinct enough to merit its own answer.

Samuel Ng's answer will work great if both objects have colliders attached.

However, there may be situations where you don't want the virtual wall-to-be-placed cursor to have a collider of its own, even a trigger. (For example, you might find it's setting off unrelated OnTriggerEnter methods elsewhere in your scene, and your layer setup may not make it easy to filter those out)

For a situation like this, you can use [Physics.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) (or, for performance, [Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc.html)). These methods give you a list of colliders in your scene overlapping a 3D box with the position, size, and orientation you specify.

You can then reject the wall placement if that list is non-empty, or filter the list in more detail to ignore minor objects that shouldn't block wall placement.